# issue in writing Unit test case for UIFont Categories

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, xcode4, iphone-developer-program

I have added methods to `UIFont` class
**.h file**

```
  @interface UIFont (UIFont_CustomisedFont)
    +(UIFont*)bold11;
    +(UIFont*)bold12;
    +(UIFont*)bold13;
```

**.m file**

```
+(UIFont*)bold11{
  return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
}
+(UIFont*)bold12{
  return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
}
+(UIFont*)bold13{
  return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
}
```

Similar way i have added so many methods to the `UIFont` category

For the above methods i have written Unit test cases using `OCUnitTest`

```
-(void)testBold11
{
    @try {
        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        lbl.font = [UIFont bold11];
    }    
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"main: Caught %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
        STFail(@"testBold11 failed");
    }
}
```

Similar UnitTestCases for other functions also

When i run the `UnitTest`, its not crashing, but stopped at one breakpoint and this message is coming  `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1385_BPT,subcode=0*0`

I didnt put any breakpoints and i am running in **"release"** mode, not in debug mode.

[image]

please assist me to fix this issue.

Comment: I've the same thing here ... any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Create a better test case, which doesn't involve the irrelevant `UILabel` class:

```
-(void)testBold11
{
    @try {
        UIFont *font = [UIFont bold11];
        STAssertNotNil(font, @"Failed to create font");
        STAssertEquals(font.pointSize, 11.0, @"Wrong point size");
    }    
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"main: Caught %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
        STFail(@"testBold11 failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a test host app (look for "test host" and "bundle loader"). Certain UIKit methods crash with such a HALT condition if you don't have such a test host.

At the simplest it is just a main.m and info.plist. Please refer to my blog post which explains [how to set up a minimalistic bundle loader](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/10/radar-double-feature-xcode-crash-and-unit-test-with-uifont/) to work around this issue.